# Google Analytics events sequence

Tags: google-analytics, sequence, google-analytics-api

I want to get from google analytics the list of events for all my users. And I want to be able to say "this event occured before this event", it means I want to know the sequence of the events, the order in which they were triggered.

I could already retrieve the list of events per user by doing a query that looks like this :

```
ids = foo
start-date = foo
end-date = foo
metrics = ga:sessions
dimensions = ga:dimensionX (dimensionX being user_id), ga:screenName,
    ga:eventCategory, ga:eventLabel, ga:eventAction, 
    ga:date,ga:hour, ga:minute
```

With this I get the list of events by user_id, by screen, and by the time (up to the minute).

But ... minutes are not enough to be sure about the sequence of events. Moreoever, I couldn't find any ga:seconds dimension (does it exist ?), so I'm not sure if trying to get the sequence by time is a good thing. That is why I was wondering if there were a way to get a kind of "id" for the event, in order to sort them by the order in which they were triggered.

If there is no such thing, I was wondering if adding an ga:eventValue and setting the value to a timestamp would be a good thing ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Event value is typically used to monetize non-e-commerce concversions, i.e. it's used e.g. to calculate your ROAS. If you use adwords storing timestamps in your event values will really mess things up (and of course in the standard reports your timestamps will be added up as regular numbers).

Comment: Sorry, I thought of ga:eventValue as a dimension, but I just saw that it's a metric so indeed it was stupid ! I am wondering then if a custom variable would do the job (but it's quite annoying since for each event the custom variable would also have to be changed, if I understood well ...)

Comment: Not sure it will work, but [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagedepth)`ga_pagedepth` as dimension could help to order events

Comment: btw, I would wonder if your code works, because you use 7 dimensions. Only 6 are allowed

Comment: @Vladimir_M In fact you [can use 7 dimensions, but not 8 ("You can supply a maximum of 7 dimensions in any query.")](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions). And I can get rid of some dimensions by using some filters so it won't be a problem. Unfortunately, pageDepth did not seem to work (and if I understood it well, it would see the differences between events inside the same page ?).